# Cutting text from comments does not put text on the clipboard

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app, comment-edits

Twice now, while typing up a comment on a question, my comment was too long, so I selected a portion of the text, tapped cut, posted the comment, then went into my notes app to save the cut text to see if I could make it more succinct, but all that’s pasted is either a space or some sort of attachment. There seems to be no way to recover the cut text that I can determine. The first time, I assumed it was a fluke or that I did something wrong, but it just happened again, so I think there’s some sort of bug in the app.

Is there a way to cut text from a comment and paste it elsewhere, like in another app? Is it just me having this issue?

Edit: I just tested it in the comments below. I typed the word “Testing”, selected it, cut it, switched to my notes app and attempted to paste. It inserted a 7 byte attachment with a name that was a long hash string and it had a Dropbox icon. There’s no way to open it to access the text.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 11.4.1 (Build 15G77)

Comment: I edit and cull down my comments in this fashion almost daily. I cut-paste to Evernote, Notepad, other comments and posts. I use Mac and Windows spanning three browsers. Works for me always. I cannot reproduce this behavior. Testing this comment on my iPhone now.

Comment: Works fine on my iPhone also. I'm wondering if it could have something to do with how you have Dropbox sync'ing set up in Notes. Might want to try pasting the comment text to another app and then pasting some text from elsewhere into Notes. Might shed some light on where the problem actually lies.

Comment: This happened to me too a while ago. It’s impossible to paste the text into places like the [regular notes app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZoZ8.jpg) (I don’t have Dropbox) or even the address bar in Safari. You can, however, recover the text if you find a webpage that converts to plain text.

Comment: I can say that I do the same thing with other apps without a problem, such as the Facebook app.

Comment: @hepcat72 makes sense, other apps get regular updates and bug fixes. SE app doesn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app)

Comment: In that, with the presumption that this is likely a bug in the SE iOS app, and that I might be able to ask this question of support or the community to get an answer/workaround, yes - it indirectly answers my question by pointing me to a place where I might more likely find a solution.